# What are the techniques to use Sockets / NIO with Zero GC Overhead?

Tags: java, sockets, garbage-collection, netty, grizzly

I am looking for techniques to use Sockets with no GCable objects created. I am looking for this as I am trying to create an application which would run on Java with GC disabled for latency. (A technique discussed here: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Extreme-FIX-Messaging-for-Low-Latency) It will receive a few million messages per second. The system can only be re started on weekly basis at the most as FX markets are open 24 hours on working days. If monitoring after market hours which would be even worse. Thus I do not have the luxury create any new objects after the system starts as this will leak memory. E.g. if I read a byte buffer which is an array object this will need to be GCed thus will run out of memory quick. I am not very sure about how efficient escape analysis on the JVM in this context as perhaps there is a chance that objects can escape.

Products like http://www.rapidaddition.com/ claim that they do not produce any GCable objects after stating up as per above presentation. This product is proprietary thus I do cannot find out how exactly this is done. If you have used any techniques to achieve similar results I would be interested in knowing how.

I am looking for the ability to read data from sockets with either.

- buffer is re used
- return only primitive data as this will need not be GCed

It should internally perform such scheme like object pooling or some other technique where there is no new objects created.

Some material I uncovered suggests frameworks like Netty, Grizzly, Mina, xSocket have some GC overhead.

http://www.znetdevelopment.com/blogs/2009/04/09/scalable-nio-servers-part-2-memory/

Other bloggs in the series:

- http://www.znetdevelopment.com/blogs/2009/04/07/scalable-nio-servers-part-1-performance/
- http://www.znetdevelopment.com/blogs/2009/04/13/scalable-nio-servers-part-3-features/
- http://www.znetdevelopment.com/blogs/2009/04/20/scalable-nio-servers-part-4-protocol/

Some additional background information:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5LQNesmht4o
http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Progressive-Architectures-at-the-Royal-Bank-of-Scotland

Comment: I am looking for a method to use NOI with little / zero GC. I am not very interested in any opinion on this. Just how this is done.

Comment: https://github.com/rfqu/pipeline is async/NIO/dataflow framework which reuses buffers and all other data containers and requires no object creation after start. It is new and not tested in production, but it is so small and simple that bugs/features can be fixed/added easily (yes it is my project).

Comment: Thus looks promising but still not that mature as it is v 0.1. Any way how does it do with garbage creation (object creation). Will be watching this.

Comment: to become mature, it has to find users... Objects are created at startup, then new object creation is not needed.

Comment: Will be willing to become an early adopter if we you would have long term commitment, fix any bugs and issues that may come up, also work with us to steer direction, regularly benchmark this with other frameworks and also try to build a community around it. Let me know your contact detail.

Comment: write to alexei dot kaigorodov at gmail dot com